# More on magnetic field outside an infinite solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

The standard argument about the vanishing of the magnetic field outside an infinite solenoid pertains to the longitudinal component, parallel to the solenoid axis. But there must be a non-zero toroidal field. However tightly the solenoid is wound, there is a net current in the longitudinal direction. Thus, by Ampere's law, there is a toroidal $B$ field whose magnitude dies off as $1/r$. Why is this field never mentioned? Or am I wrong?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/292696/78842

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you're correct, and in fact, it's mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#Outside):

> Of course, if the solenoid is constructed as a wire spiral (as often done in practice), then it emanates an outside field the same way as a single wire, due to the current flowing overall down the length of the solenoid.

Comment: In his pioneering experiments in the 1820s, Ampère knew about this field due to the longitudinal current in a coil, and corrected for it.

Comment: See Example 5.9 in the fourth edition of "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by David J. Griffiths.

Comment: These were interesting and instructive answers.